# Ionic 2 CloudModule Crypto.js Error

Tags: ionic2

I'm referring to https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html to add my app to Ionic View. Whenever I add the line `CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)` as per the above tutorial it throws below error

```
[INFO] Starting app-scripts server: --lab --l --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --address 0.0.0.0 - Ctrl+C to cancel
[18:39:44]  watch started ...
[18:39:44]  build dev started ...
[18:39:44]  clean started ...
[18:39:44]  clean finished in 5 ms
[18:39:44]  copy started ...
[18:39:44]  transpile started ...
[18:39:48]  transpile finished in 4.35 s
[18:39:48]  preprocess started ...
[18:39:48]  deeplinks started ...
[18:39:48]  deeplinks finished in 56 ms
[18:39:48]  preprocess finished in 60 ms
[18:39:48]  webpack started ...
[18:39:48]  copy finished in 4.71 s

crypto.js:74
  this._handle.update(data, encoding);
               ^

TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer
    at TypeError (native)
    at Hash.update (crypto.js:74:16)
    at HarmonyExportImportedSpecifierDependency.updateHash (G:\Projects\Fortuna\Atithi\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyExportImportedSpecifierDependency.js:144:8)
    at G:\Projects\Fortuna\Atithi\node_modules\webpack\lib\DependenciesBlock.js:33:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at NormalModule.DependenciesBlock.updateHash (G:\Projects\Fortuna\Atithi\node_modules\webpack\lib\DependenciesBlock.js:32:20)
    at NormalModule.Module.updateHash (G:\Projects\Fortuna\Atithi\node_modules\webpack\lib\Module.js:162:41)
    at NormalModule.updateHash (G:\Projects\Fortuna\Atithi\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:327:30)
    at modules.forEach.m (G:\Projects\Fortuna\Atithi\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:253:31)
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

I already tried doing `npm install @ionic/cloud-angular@latest --save` but it didn't resolved the issue.

Can anyone please help me resolving it? Anyone else faced it before?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but on my regular Angular 4 app. It was because of the @angular/material library that updated to 2.0.0-beta.8 so I downgraded to 2.0.0-beta.7 and it started working again. Hope this helps :D